# How to pull top 2 highest sum values based on two column categorical values in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, subset

Here is my dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("buildinga", "buildingb", "buildingc"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                      2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Food", "Beverage", "Food"), 
                                                                                       class = "factor"), 
                     units_sold = c(200, 250, 150, 180, 200, 80, 140, 200, 210)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    -9L))



print(df)

Location Category units_sold
1 buildinga     Food        200
2 buildinga     Food        250
3 buildinga Beverage        150
4 buildingb     Food        180
5 buildingb Beverage        200
6 buildingb     Food         80
7 buildingc Beverage        140
8 buildingc Beverage        200
9 buildingc     Food        210
```

**I would like to pull the top two values from units sold for both Beverage and Food for each location**. This will tell me what the top two grouped products are per location when looking at units sold.

I was trying this if-else statement but did not get any output:

```
ifelse(Location == Location & Category == Category & units_sold == max(units_sold), new_df
```

I tried using group_by with arrange order but I could not get the output I wanted. Goal is to export the 2 items per location as a csv file.

Comment: You example doesn't have sufficient data but I think you need `df %>%
  group_by(Location, Category)  %>%
  top_n(2, units_sold)
` in `dplyr`

Comment: @Ronak Shah I tried that - however my condition needs to give the the top food AND beverage item. When I run this it just gives the top two items, regardless of category factored in to give the top Food and top Bev item...I'm working on a while statement but not sure if something else would be easier to adjust the group_by statement..

Comment: Can you show expected output for the example you have shared ?